Identify this Punjabi film about 1984's Anti-Sikh riots?
I remember a Punjabi (Indian) movie about 1984's anti-Sikh riots. The hero helps terrorists to stay in their house for a night (Because the terrorists are having weapons and he doesn't have any other option). Even one of the terrorists is a known person to him (maybe his old classmate from college/school). I think the actress playing his wife is Juhi Chawla but googling didn't help me.
The whole plot revolves around trouble causing to hero's family due to the terrorists stay in their house. He and his family faces abuse from police and maybe from society too. And they help the hero to go underground or help him to go abroad. In the end, He comes back for his wife to meet her but he dies in police firing in front of her.
So, does anybody know which film this is?

Finally, I was successful in finding it by reading all the plot-lines of Juhi's Punjabi films from IMDb. And the movie is Des Hoyaa Pardes, which also got the 2004's National Award in best regional film category.
